# angular-seo doesn't render the ui-view content

Tags: angularjs, seo

I'm using angular-seo
but it doesn't render
the ui-view content.

My set up:

```
.config(function($locationProvider,$stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
    $stateProvider
       .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'src/app/default/site/site.tpl.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .state('blog', {
            url: '/blog',
            templateUrl: 'src/app/default/blog/blog.tpl.html',
            resolve: {
                posts: function(Post){
                    return Post.all();
                }
            },
            controller: 'BlogIndexCtrl'
        })
})
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
angular.module('app', ['seo']);
.controller('BlogIndexCtrl', function ($scope,posts) {
    $scope.posts =  posts;
    $scope.htmlReady();
})




phantomjs --disk-cache=no ~/vendor/angular-seo/angular-seo-server.js 5000 http://localhost
```

but when I run

```
curl 'http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=/blog'
```

I only get the html without the innner ui-view content :(

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put $scope.htmlReady on [$viewContentLoaded](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events) event?

Comment: good point but it doesn't work I put it in the run block   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(evt) {
            //console.log(evt);
            $rootScope.htmlReady();
        });

Comment: I don't use angular-seo (just for small things), but looking at [server side code](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo/blob/master/angular-seo-server.js#L48) I think that it expects just hashbang URL and it doesn't work in html5Mode. Can you try without html5Mode and let me know?

Comment: it's quite hard to change the code to switch to # but when I've got a little time I'll try it.Thanks for caring :)